# ADA: How to indicate that a generic parameter can be converted to Float

Tags: ada

In this example I am trying to define a generic that accept all numeric types and create a pair type with two operations: addition, and (right) multiplication by a scalar of type float.

```
Compiling: pair.ads
Source file time stamp: 2021-03-10 02:36:51
Compiled at: 2021-03-09 21:36:52

     1. generic
     2.    type T is private;
     3.    with function "+" (a, b : T) return T is <>;
     4.
     5. package pair is
     6.     subtype T1 is T;
     7.     type P is array (1 .. 2) of T1;
     8.   
     9.     function "*" (a : T1; f : Float) return T1 is 
    10.         (T1 (Float'rounding (Float (a) * f)));
                                            |
        >>> illegal operand for numeric conversion

    11.
    12.     function "+" (a,b : P) return P is
    13.         ((a (1) + b (1), a (2) + b (2)));
    14.
    15.     function "*" (a : P; f : Float) return P is
    16.         ((a (1) * f, a (2) * f));
    17. end pair;

 17 lines: 1 error
```

Line 3 indicates the private type T has "+" operator but I don't know how to indicate that T is convertible to Float, and therefore I get an error in line 10.

A second problem is when instantiating with 'Float', the function at line 9 becomes ambiguous because the type Float already has multiplication by float scalar.

How do I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Ada is a strongly typed language. There is actually no safe way to convert an arbitrary type, such as a record type, an array type or a task type into a float. Ada Language Reference Manual section 12.5.2 Formal Scalar Types describes the generic parameter descriptions for all formal scalar types. Enumeration types have no "+" function since they are not arithmetic types.

Comment: Do you mean the American Dental Association or Aged and Disability Advocates? Ada is a woman's name, not an acronym.

Comment: @JimRogers 
The domain is signal processing, and T indeed cannot be arbitrary - ideally T  would denote a field (R or C) then we can talk of an Algebra. In practice we often deal with numbers in range 0 .. 2**n, which are not even closed under subtraction for example...

It would help and solve part of the problem if I could limit T only to arithmetic types, but I don't know how.

Comment: @PolarBear2015 Numbers in the range of 0..2**n sound suspiciously like a modular type. Ada defines addition and subtraction for such a type with wrap-around semantics. One is hardware limited on values for such a type. For instance, on a 64 bit architecture the maximum value of n would be 64:
type T is mod 2 ** 64;

Comment: @PolarBear2015 The generic formal parameter for a modular type is: type T is mod <>;

Comment: @JimRogers - 0..2**n is what most hardware A/D produce - just a some HW with a given number of bits.  Many times it makes sense to convert the raw input into float (0..1.0), which is why I used type: T is private.
The semantic is saturation semantics (does not wrap), which can be defined in Ada, of course, just didn't get to this point yet.

Answer (score 4):

Your clients must provide functions to convert T to Float and Float to T:

```
   with function To_T (Value : in Float) return T;
   with function To_Float (Value : in T) return Float;
...
      To_T (To_Float (A) * F);
```

or a function to mutliply a T and a Float returning a T:

```
   with function "*" (Left : in T; Right : in Float) return T;
```

(Why do you declare the subtype `T1`? It doesn't gain you anything.)

Comment: Jeffrey, 
Thank you, it is helpful!
 
Regarding subtype T1 - I wasn't sure if it is needed myself, 
but did not want to overload the question.
Regarding Ada not being an acronym - I'm not a native English speaker - I missed that.
(Unfortunately, search engines do not make this distinction,  whenever I type Ada, I do get all the acronyms in the search results...)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I usually use in cases like this is requiring that there exists a function "conversion to float" for type T, something like

```
   with function To_Float(X : T) return Float is <>;
```

I guess this is the best way to express the constraint "T must be convertible to Float."

Answer (score 1):

I now understand better what you are trying to do. Try the following approach:

```
generic
   Num_Bits : Positive;
   type Raw_Signal is Range <>;
package pairs is
   subtype Normal_Value is Long_Float range 0.0..1.0;
   function Normalize(Value : in Raw_Signal) return Normal_Value;
end pairs;

package body pairs is

   ---------------
   -- Normalize --
   ---------------

   function Normalize (Value : in Raw_Signal) return Normal_Value is
   begin
      return Long_Float(Value) / 2.0**Num_Bits;
   end Normalize;

end pairs;

with Pairs;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   Bits : constant := 8;
   type Byte_Signal is range 0..2**Bits - 1;
   package bytes is new pairs(Num_Bits   => Bits,
                              Raw_Signal => Byte_Signal);
   use bytes;
begin
   for I in Byte_Signal'Range loop
      Put(I'Image & " : ");
      Put_Line(Normal_Value'Image(Normalize(I)));
   end loop;
   
end Main;
```

The output of the program shows the proper conversion of an 8-bit number to a long_float.

```
 0 :  0.00000000000000E+00
 1 :  3.90625000000000E-03
 2 :  7.81250000000000E-03
 3 :  1.17187500000000E-02
 4 :  1.56250000000000E-02
 5 :  1.95312500000000E-02
 6 :  2.34375000000000E-02
 7 :  2.73437500000000E-02
 8 :  3.12500000000000E-02
 9 :  3.51562500000000E-02
 10 :  3.90625000000000E-02
 11 :  4.29687500000000E-02
 12 :  4.68750000000000E-02
 13 :  5.07812500000000E-02
 14 :  5.46875000000000E-02
 15 :  5.85937500000000E-02
 16 :  6.25000000000000E-02
 17 :  6.64062500000000E-02
 18 :  7.03125000000000E-02
 19 :  7.42187500000000E-02
 20 :  7.81250000000000E-02
 21 :  8.20312500000000E-02
 22 :  8.59375000000000E-02
 23 :  8.98437500000000E-02
 24 :  9.37500000000000E-02
 25 :  9.76562500000000E-02
 26 :  1.01562500000000E-01
 27 :  1.05468750000000E-01
 28 :  1.09375000000000E-01
 29 :  1.13281250000000E-01
 30 :  1.17187500000000E-01
 31 :  1.21093750000000E-01
 32 :  1.25000000000000E-01
 33 :  1.28906250000000E-01
 34 :  1.32812500000000E-01
 35 :  1.36718750000000E-01
 36 :  1.40625000000000E-01
 37 :  1.44531250000000E-01
 38 :  1.48437500000000E-01
 39 :  1.52343750000000E-01
 40 :  1.56250000000000E-01
 41 :  1.60156250000000E-01
 42 :  1.64062500000000E-01
 43 :  1.67968750000000E-01
 44 :  1.71875000000000E-01
 45 :  1.75781250000000E-01
 46 :  1.79687500000000E-01
 47 :  1.83593750000000E-01
 48 :  1.87500000000000E-01
 49 :  1.91406250000000E-01
 50 :  1.95312500000000E-01
 51 :  1.99218750000000E-01
 52 :  2.03125000000000E-01
 53 :  2.07031250000000E-01
 54 :  2.10937500000000E-01
 55 :  2.14843750000000E-01
 56 :  2.18750000000000E-01
 57 :  2.22656250000000E-01
 58 :  2.26562500000000E-01
 59 :  2.30468750000000E-01
 60 :  2.34375000000000E-01
 61 :  2.38281250000000E-01
 62 :  2.42187500000000E-01
 63 :  2.46093750000000E-01
 64 :  2.50000000000000E-01
 65 :  2.53906250000000E-01
 66 :  2.57812500000000E-01
 67 :  2.61718750000000E-01
 68 :  2.65625000000000E-01
 69 :  2.69531250000000E-01
 70 :  2.73437500000000E-01
 71 :  2.77343750000000E-01
 72 :  2.81250000000000E-01
 73 :  2.85156250000000E-01
 74 :  2.89062500000000E-01
 75 :  2.92968750000000E-01
 76 :  2.96875000000000E-01
 77 :  3.00781250000000E-01
 78 :  3.04687500000000E-01
 79 :  3.08593750000000E-01
 80 :  3.12500000000000E-01
 81 :  3.16406250000000E-01
 82 :  3.20312500000000E-01
 83 :  3.24218750000000E-01
 84 :  3.28125000000000E-01
 85 :  3.32031250000000E-01
 86 :  3.35937500000000E-01
 87 :  3.39843750000000E-01
 88 :  3.43750000000000E-01
 89 :  3.47656250000000E-01
 90 :  3.51562500000000E-01
 91 :  3.55468750000000E-01
 92 :  3.59375000000000E-01
 93 :  3.63281250000000E-01
 94 :  3.67187500000000E-01
 95 :  3.71093750000000E-01
 96 :  3.75000000000000E-01
 97 :  3.78906250000000E-01
 98 :  3.82812500000000E-01
 99 :  3.86718750000000E-01
 100 :  3.90625000000000E-01
 101 :  3.94531250000000E-01
 102 :  3.98437500000000E-01
 103 :  4.02343750000000E-01
 104 :  4.06250000000000E-01
 105 :  4.10156250000000E-01
 106 :  4.14062500000000E-01
 107 :  4.17968750000000E-01
 108 :  4.21875000000000E-01
 109 :  4.25781250000000E-01
 110 :  4.29687500000000E-01
 111 :  4.33593750000000E-01
 112 :  4.37500000000000E-01
 113 :  4.41406250000000E-01
 114 :  4.45312500000000E-01
 115 :  4.49218750000000E-01
 116 :  4.53125000000000E-01
 117 :  4.57031250000000E-01
 118 :  4.60937500000000E-01
 119 :  4.64843750000000E-01
 120 :  4.68750000000000E-01
 121 :  4.72656250000000E-01
 122 :  4.76562500000000E-01
 123 :  4.80468750000000E-01
 124 :  4.84375000000000E-01
 125 :  4.88281250000000E-01
 126 :  4.92187500000000E-01
 127 :  4.96093750000000E-01
 128 :  5.00000000000000E-01
 129 :  5.03906250000000E-01
 130 :  5.07812500000000E-01
 131 :  5.11718750000000E-01
 132 :  5.15625000000000E-01
 133 :  5.19531250000000E-01
 134 :  5.23437500000000E-01
 135 :  5.27343750000000E-01
 136 :  5.31250000000000E-01
 137 :  5.35156250000000E-01
 138 :  5.39062500000000E-01
 139 :  5.42968750000000E-01
 140 :  5.46875000000000E-01
 141 :  5.50781250000000E-01
 142 :  5.54687500000000E-01
 143 :  5.58593750000000E-01
 144 :  5.62500000000000E-01
 145 :  5.66406250000000E-01
 146 :  5.70312500000000E-01
 147 :  5.74218750000000E-01
 148 :  5.78125000000000E-01
 149 :  5.82031250000000E-01
 150 :  5.85937500000000E-01
 151 :  5.89843750000000E-01
 152 :  5.93750000000000E-01
 153 :  5.97656250000000E-01
 154 :  6.01562500000000E-01
 155 :  6.05468750000000E-01
 156 :  6.09375000000000E-01
 157 :  6.13281250000000E-01
 158 :  6.17187500000000E-01
 159 :  6.21093750000000E-01
 160 :  6.25000000000000E-01
 161 :  6.28906250000000E-01
 162 :  6.32812500000000E-01
 163 :  6.36718750000000E-01
 164 :  6.40625000000000E-01
 165 :  6.44531250000000E-01
 166 :  6.48437500000000E-01
 167 :  6.52343750000000E-01
 168 :  6.56250000000000E-01
 169 :  6.60156250000000E-01
 170 :  6.64062500000000E-01
 171 :  6.67968750000000E-01
 172 :  6.71875000000000E-01
 173 :  6.75781250000000E-01
 174 :  6.79687500000000E-01
 175 :  6.83593750000000E-01
 176 :  6.87500000000000E-01
 177 :  6.91406250000000E-01
 178 :  6.95312500000000E-01
 179 :  6.99218750000000E-01
 180 :  7.03125000000000E-01
 181 :  7.07031250000000E-01
 182 :  7.10937500000000E-01
 183 :  7.14843750000000E-01
 184 :  7.18750000000000E-01
 185 :  7.22656250000000E-01
 186 :  7.26562500000000E-01
 187 :  7.30468750000000E-01
 188 :  7.34375000000000E-01
 189 :  7.38281250000000E-01
 190 :  7.42187500000000E-01
 191 :  7.46093750000000E-01
 192 :  7.50000000000000E-01
 193 :  7.53906250000000E-01
 194 :  7.57812500000000E-01
 195 :  7.61718750000000E-01
 196 :  7.65625000000000E-01
 197 :  7.69531250000000E-01
 198 :  7.73437500000000E-01
 199 :  7.77343750000000E-01
 200 :  7.81250000000000E-01
 201 :  7.85156250000000E-01
 202 :  7.89062500000000E-01
 203 :  7.92968750000000E-01
 204 :  7.96875000000000E-01
 205 :  8.00781250000000E-01
 206 :  8.04687500000000E-01
 207 :  8.08593750000000E-01
 208 :  8.12500000000000E-01
 209 :  8.16406250000000E-01
 210 :  8.20312500000000E-01
 211 :  8.24218750000000E-01
 212 :  8.28125000000000E-01
 213 :  8.32031250000000E-01
 214 :  8.35937500000000E-01
 215 :  8.39843750000000E-01
 216 :  8.43750000000000E-01
 217 :  8.47656250000000E-01
 218 :  8.51562500000000E-01
 219 :  8.55468750000000E-01
 220 :  8.59375000000000E-01
 221 :  8.63281250000000E-01
 222 :  8.67187500000000E-01
 223 :  8.71093750000000E-01
 224 :  8.75000000000000E-01
 225 :  8.78906250000000E-01
 226 :  8.82812500000000E-01
 227 :  8.86718750000000E-01
 228 :  8.90625000000000E-01
 229 :  8.94531250000000E-01
 230 :  8.98437500000000E-01
 231 :  9.02343750000000E-01
 232 :  9.06250000000000E-01
 233 :  9.10156250000000E-01
 234 :  9.14062500000000E-01
 235 :  9.17968750000000E-01
 236 :  9.21875000000000E-01
 237 :  9.25781250000000E-01
 238 :  9.29687500000000E-01
 239 :  9.33593750000000E-01
 240 :  9.37500000000000E-01
 241 :  9.41406250000000E-01
 242 :  9.45312500000000E-01
 243 :  9.49218750000000E-01
 244 :  9.53125000000000E-01
 245 :  9.57031250000000E-01
 246 :  9.60937500000000E-01
 247 :  9.64843750000000E-01
 248 :  9.68750000000000E-01
 249 :  9.72656250000000E-01
 250 :  9.76562500000000E-01
 251 :  9.80468750000000E-01
 252 :  9.84375000000000E-01
 253 :  9.88281250000000E-01
 254 :  9.92187500000000E-01
 255 :  9.96093750000000E-01
```

Comment: Thank you!,  Yes, this is a much cleaner solution than what I was trying to do.

Comment: I remember  solving this problem about 20 years ago. We needed to implement a normalized floating point value from an A/D converter while making future maintenance easy when the A/D converter was upgraded to more bits, such as a 14 bit A/D to a 16 bit A/D. The software receiving the normalized value should be unaware of the hardware change.